# java how to extract some property from a List of some object and also friendly to refactor

Tags: java

When develop java code, always need extract some property from a list of some object, e.g.

```
List<Foo> fooList = ...
List<Integer> idList = new ArrayList<>();
for(Foo f : fooList){
    idList.add(f.getId());
}
```

because in production environment we used `java7`, so I cannot use `java8` stream to implement this. So I write an util code to implement this

```
public static <T, O> List<T> extract(Collection<O> collection, String propertyName) {
    List<T> result = new ArrayList<>(collection.size());
    for (O o : collection) {
        Object val = getFieldValue(propertyName, o);
        result.add((T) val);
    }
    return result;
}
```

then I implement this just like below

```
List<Integer> idList = extract(fooList,"id");
```

but it's not friendly to refactor, if I changed the property name,e.g. id --> fooId, it cannot perceive to this change.

So I want to know how to implement this function refactor friendly and also use it easily?

Comment: To be honest, the first normal java 7 way looks much cleaner and easy to read than using your utility class. Some things are better just left untouched. You could alternatively take a look at the actual Java 8 stream class and try and imitate their logic.

Comment: Do you actually need this genericity? How many distinct properties are you using this mapping function for?

Answer (score 3):

Even if you don't use Java 8, you can apply the same logic by using a function as next:

```
public interface Function<T, R> {
    /**
     * Applies this function to the given argument.
     *
     * @param t the function argument
     * @return the function result
     */
    R apply(T t);
}

public static <T, O> List<T> extract(Collection<O> collection, Function<O, T> mapper) {
    List<T> result = new ArrayList<>(collection.size());
    for (O o : collection) {
        result.add(mapper.apply(o));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Indeed using a function instead of a `String literal` is much easier to refactor and much more Object Oriented.

Your method call will then be something like that:

```
List<Integer> idList = extract(fooList, new Function<Foo, Integer>() {
    @Override
    public Integer apply(final Foo f) {
        return f.getId();
    }
});
```

Comment: I was about to post this :) Maybe you can add an explanation on how to use this in a non-java8 environment (with an anonymous class maybe?), because I think that's what OP is interested in.

Comment: Yes precisely. I think readers of this post are looking for this, because copy-pasting Java 8's `Function` and `map()` is easy, but getting the caller code right is harder.

Comment: Thanks, but actually I'm not very like anonymous, I think it's not intuitive. And I think `lambdaj` is more intuitive, e.g. `extract(fooList, on(Foo.class).getId());` but its source code is a little difficult to understand.Please see https://code.google.com/archive/p/lambdaj/wikis/LambdajFeatures.wiki

Comment: Be careful it seems to not be maintained anymore, the last release has been done in 2012 according to https://code.google.com/archive/p/lambdaj/downloads

Answer (score 1):

I think you can have a look to Guava. Guava has a Function interface and
`Collections2.transform(Collection<E>, Function<E,E2>)` method provides the feature you require. Following is an example:

```
final Collection<Foo> fooList = ...;
final Collection<Integer> idList =
    Collections2.transform(fooList, new Function<Foo, Integer>(){

        @Override
        public Integer apply(final Foo foo){
            return foo.getId();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, but actually I'm not very like anonymous, I think it's not intuitive. And I think `lambdaj` is more  intuitive, e.g. `extract(fooList, on(Foo.class).getId());` but its source code is a little difficult to understand.Please see https://code.google.com/archive/p/lambdaj/wikis/LambdajFeatures.wiki